# What is the proper way to use the backend_config map with RubyTerraform::Commands::Init

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, terraform

What is the proper way to use the `backend_config` map with the `RubyTerraform::Commands::Init` command?

If I use the variable name, `backend_config` as it is defined in the documentation, I get the runtime error, `uninitialized constant RubyTerraform::Options::Values::Complex::JSON (NameError)`.  *See below for the actual error message*.

I noticed that the RubyTerraform library converted the Terraform command line option `var` to a plural `vars`.  So, I tried using `backend_configs`.  *See below for the actual code*.

My results was that that the code that uses `backend_configs` will execute without any runtime errors, but when I check the S3 bucket, there is no terraform state file.  Per suggestion from @Allisoin, I found that if I add the line `require 'json'`, it resolves the error message, and neither form of the option generate an error message.

But, they also don't produce a state file.  I am guessing that Terraform won't produce a state file, for an empty project, and I need to actually add some actual infrastructure code to get it to save the state.

Example code, with `backend_configs`.

```
require 'ruby-terraform'
require 'json' # makes the error message for 'backend_config' go away

puts "Testing creating parameters"
RubyTerraform.init(
    chdir: 'terraform',
    backend_configs: {
        bucket: '<myAWSAccountNumber>-terraform-state-files',
        dynamodb_table: 'terraform_locks',
        key: "deleteME/terraform.tfstate",
        encrypt: true,
        region: "us-east-1"
    }
)
```

Result message that I get when running with `backend_configs`.

```
Testing creating parameters
Initializing the backend...
Initializing provider plugins...
Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.

Process exited with code: 0
```

**Note**: There is no Terraform state file in the s3 bucket.

Here is the error that I get when using `backend_config`.

**Note**: The error message below provides the version numbers for both Ruby and the [Ruby_Terraform](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-terraform/) library that I am using.

```
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/ruby-terraform-1.3.1/lib/ruby_terraform/options/values/complex.rb:14:in `render': uninitialized constant RubyTerraform::Options::Values::Complex::JSON (NameError)
```

Comment: This may be a bug in the gem.

Comment: The option should be `backend_config` according to the source code, but there may be a bug with this line needing to call `JSON` as `::JSON` instead: https://github.com/infrablocks/ruby_terraform/blob/master/lib/ruby_terraform/options/values/complex.rb#L14

Comment: I don't see json in their lockfile at all: https://github.com/infrablocks/ruby_terraform/blob/master/Gemfile.lock 
does it work if you require json in your project file where this is called?

Comment: Allison, Adding "require 'json'" to the sample file made the error message go away.  So, now, both forms "backend_config" and "backend_configs" yield the same results.

Comment: What probably makes both options work is the Options module.  See the options for 'override' at the https://github.com/infrablocks/ruby_terraform/blob/master/lib/ruby_terraform/options/definitions.rb#L20.